# Stop XHR responding to OPTIONS request

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I'm building an API which will be hosted in Azure functions and a Web App that will be hosted on Azure Blob storage. This means my API has to respond to OPTIONS requests from the users browser (which isn't an issue when using Postman or Curl).

My API responds appropriately to the OPTIONS requests so this removes any CORS issues.

The issue occurs when the server responds to the OPTIONS on the client side Javascript. It appears to be taking that as the response and ignore the real response. How do I stop XHR from accepting the OPTIONS response?

Here is my function:

```
function makeRequest(method, url, data) {
  document.body.style.cursor = "wait";
  return new Promise (function (resolve, reject) {
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open(method, url)
    xhr.onload = function () {
      if (this.status == 200) {
        authToken = this.getResponseHeader('Authorization');
        document.body.style.cursor = "initial";
        console.log('responseText');
        console.log(this.responseText);
        resolve(JSON.parse(this.responseText));
      } else if (this.status == 403) {
        logout();
        document.body.style.cursor = "initial";
        reject({
                    status: this.status,
                    statusText: xhr.statusText
                });
      } else {
        document.body.innerHTML = 'Error: ' + this.responseText;
        document.body.style.cursor = "initial";
        reject({
                    status: this.status,
                    statusText: xhr.statusText
                });
      }
    };
    xhr.onerror = function () {
            document.body.innerHTML = 'Error: ' + this.responseText;
            document.body.style.cursor = "initial";
            reject({
                status: this.status,
                statusText: xhr.statusText
            });
        };
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", authToken);
        xhr.send(data);
  });
}
```

This works but I can't use it as my App needs to be able to await the response from the function before moving on to the next thing:

```
function retrieveCategories(active) {
  document.body.style.cursor = "wait";
  var data = JSON.stringify({
  "active": active
});
console.log(data);

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.withCredentials = true;

xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
  if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status == 403) {
    logout();
    document.body.style.cursor = "initial";
  } else if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status != 200) {
    document.body.innerHTML = 'Error: ' + this.responseText;
    document.body.style.cursor = "initial";
  } else if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status == 200) {
    authToken = this.getResponseHeader('Authorization');
    categories = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    document.body.style.cursor = "initial";
  }
});

xhr.open("POST", "http://127.0.0.1:7071/retrievecategories");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", authToken);

xhr.send(data);
}
```

Ideas greatly appreciated!

Comment: "The issue occurs when the server responds to the OPTIONS on the client side Javascript. It appears to be taking that as the response and ignore the real response." — That won't happen. Whatever the problem is, you've misidentified it.

Comment: Thanks @Quentin, that is entirely possible, may sleep and another go at it again tomorrow will uncover the true issue. In the interim, do have any ideas what is causing it? I can see the server responding correctly, and looking at the network traffic in the console shows the first an OPTIONS response with a status of 200 and then the real response, again with a status of 200.

Answer (score -1):

@Quentin was correct, XHR was not responding to the OPTIONS response as I originally thought. The server was sending a malformed response